# Heat equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions and time dependent sink

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am looking for some guidance on how to go about solving the following problem

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2} - \phi'(t)$$
Boundary conditions:

\begin{align} v(0,t) &= 0 \\ \quad v(a,t) &= 0\end{align}
Initial conditions:
$$v(r,0) = -w(r,0)$$
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use the method of eigenfunction expansion - http://www.web.pdx.edu/~daescu/mth427_527/notes_weeks6-7.pdf